# Cutting continuous variable into predefined blocks with custom labels

Tags: r, vectors

## Background

The function makes use of [`cut`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/cut) function offered in R's base package in order to "bin" a numeric vector into provided categories and apply, meaningful user, friendly labels.

### Example

For vector:

```
set.seed(1); x <- runif(10)
[1] 0.26550866 0.37212390 ...
```

and brackets `c(0.1, 0.3)`

The function would return *(for the two values above):*

```
0.1 >= your_value <= 0.3
your_value >= 0.3
```

---

## Implementation

```
cut_into_bins <- function(x, bin_groups, value_name = "your_value") {
  # Sort vector
  bin_groups <- sort(bin_groups)

  # Ensure infinity at the ends
  if (head(bin_groups, 1) != Inf) {
    bin_groups <- append(bin_groups, -Inf, 0)
  }
  if (tail(bin_groups, 1) != Inf) {
    bin_groups <- append(bin_groups, Inf)
  }

  # Create labels
  lbls <- NULL
  i <- 1
  while (i < length(bin_groups)) {
    lbls[i] <- paste(bin_groups[i], bin_groups[i + 1])
    i <- i + 1
  }
  lbls <- sapply(
    X = lbls,
    FUN = function(x) {
      if (grepl("-Inf", x, fixed = TRUE)) {
        gsub("-Inf", paste(value_name, "<="), x)
      } else if (grepl("Inf", x, fixed = TRUE)) {
        x <- gsub("Inf", "", x)
        paste(value_name, ">=", x)
      } else {
        gsub("(\\d+\\.\\d+)(\\s)(\\d+\\.\\d+)", paste("\\1 <=", value_name ,"<= \\3"), x)
      }
    }
  )

  # Cut and return simple character vector
  res <-
    cut.default(
      x = x,
      breaks = bin_groups,
      include.lowest = TRUE,
      right = TRUE,
      labels = lbls
    )

  as.character(trimws(res))
}
```

### Testing

```
sample_vec <-
  c(
    -198,-19292.221,-0.5,
    0.1,
    0.8,
    0.3,
    0.11,
    0.5,
    0.55,
    0.6,
    0.72,
    -0.72,
    0.95,
    1,
    1.2,
    9829082,
    2092
  )

custom_bands <- c(0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.75, 0.9)

# Run function
res <- cut_into_bins(x = sample_vec, bin_groups = custom_bands)
# print(matrix(data = c(sample_vec, res), ncol = 2))
```

#### Results

```
#      [,1]         [,2]                       
# [1,] "-198"       "your_value <= 0.1"        
# [2,] "-19292.221" "your_value <= 0.1"        
# [3,] "-0.5"       "your_value <= 0.1"        
# [4,] "0.1"        "your_value <= 0.1"        
# [5,] "0.8"        "0.75 <= your_value <= 0.9"
# [6,] "0.3"        "0.1 <= your_value <= 0.5" 
# [7,] "0.11"       "0.1 <= your_value <= 0.5" 
# [8,] "0.5"        "0.1 <= your_value <= 0.5" 
# [9,] "0.55"       "0.5 <= your_value <= 0.6" 
# [10,] "0.6"        "0.5 <= your_value <= 0.6" 
# [11,] "0.72"       "0.6 <= your_value <= 0.75"
# [12,] "-0.72"      "your_value <= 0.1"        
# [13,] "0.95"       "your_value >= 0.9"        
# [14,] "1"          "your_value >= 0.9"        
# [15,] "1.2"        "your_value >= 0.9"        
# [16,] "9829082"    "your_value >= 0.9"        
# [17,] "2092"       "your_value >= 0.9"
```

---

## Sought feedback

In particular, I'm interested in comments addressing the following:

- The way object `lols` is constructed is inelegant. In particular, I don't appreciate reliance on `gsub`; what would be wiser approach to this challenge?
- Are there any edge cases that function may not capture?

  - In the actual implementation I'm also testing for correct types of passed vectors: `x` and `bin_groups` so there is no risk of strings being passed instead of numeric vectors, etc.

---

## Some afterthoughs ...

Following [@minem's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/143127/minem) [reply](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/248537/94838), I've run some benchmarking tests on different approaches to label creation:

```
# Functions ---------------------------------------------------------------

unique_sort <- function(x) {
    x <- c(Inf, -Inf, x)
    x <- unique(x)
    sort(x)
}

sort_unique <- function(x) {
    x <- c(Inf, -Inf, x)
    x <- sort(x)
    unique(x)
}

if_logic <- function(x) {
    if (head(x, 1) != Inf) {
        x <- append(x, -Inf, 0)
    }
    if (tail(x, 1) != Inf) {
        x <- append(x, Inf)
    }
}

# Benchmark ---------------------------------------------------------------

bands <- c(0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.75, 0.9)
bench::mark(
    unique_sort(x = bands),
    sort_unique(x = bands),
    if_logic(x = bands)
)
```

### Results

It would appear that clunky `if` approach performs better; although, this is not something that is relevant to this function as labels are created only once...

```
# A tibble: 3 x 13
  expression                  min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result  memory   time    gc     
  <bch:expr>             <bch:tm> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>  <list>   <list>  <list> 
1 unique_sort(x = bands)  30.01µs  33.7µs    27365.        0B    13.7   9995     5      365ms <dbl [… <Rprofm… <bch:t… <tibbl…
2 sort_unique(x = bands)  30.38µs  61.2µs    14340.        0B     8.87  6466     4      451ms <dbl [… <Rprofm… <bch:t… <tibbl…
3 if_logic(x = bands)      9.32µs  11.6µs    84078.        0B    16.8   9998     2      119ms <dbl [… <Rprofm… <bch:t… <tibbl…
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would adjust the function like:

```
cut_into_bins2 <- function(x, bin_groups, value_name = "your_value") {
  
  # Ensure infinity at the ends
  bin_groups <- c(-Inf, Inf, bin_groups)
  bin_groups <- unique(bin_groups)
  bin_groups <- sort(bin_groups)
  
  # Create labels
  bin_groups2 <- bin_groups[-length(bin_groups)][-1]
  n2 <- length(bin_groups2)
  lbls <- c(
    sprintf("%s <= %s", value_name, bin_groups2[1]),
    sprintf("%s < %s <= %s", bin_groups2[-n2], value_name, bin_groups2[-1]),
    sprintf("%s < %s", bin_groups2[n2], value_name)
    )
  
  # Cut and return simple character vector
  res <-
    cut.default(
      x = x,
      breaks = bin_groups,
      include.lowest = TRUE,
      right = TRUE,
      labels = lbls
    )
  res
  return(as.character(res))
}
```

1. shorter addition of Inf values. We add them, take unique values and then sort.
2. rewrote creation of labels. As we know all values are unique and sorted we can create the labels like this. + adjusted the labels to match the results ('<' instead of '<=' for interval matching)